# не прокручивается (при помощи клавиатуры) html страница без предварительного щелчка мыши по контенту

Tags: html

Заказчик просит прокрутку при помощи клавиатуры, но она срабатывает только при активации body мышкой, видимо из-за кучи слоев, которые необходимы для создания параллакс эффекта. Нужно, чтобы возможность прокрутки клавиатурой была доступна сразу после загрузки страницы. Как этого добиться? Я так понимаю, что можно это реализовать при помощи java-script, но знаний в этой области мало.

```
    <html>
     <body>
      <header class="cd-header">
        <nav></nav>
      </header>
    <div class="parallax">
        <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
          <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
            <div class="title main_title"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
          <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
            <div class="title"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
            <div class="title"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="group3" class="parallax__group">
          <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--fore">
            <div class="title"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
            <div class="title text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="group4" class="parallax__group">
          <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
            <div class="title"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back parallax__layer--back--1">
            <div class="title"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--deep">
            <div class="title"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="group5" class="parallax__group">
          <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--fore">
            <div class="title"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
              <div class="title text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="group6" class="parallax__group">
            <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
              <div class="title"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
              <div class="title"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="group7" class="parallax__group">
            <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
              <div class="title text">             
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="group6" class="parallax__group">
            <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
              <div class="title"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
              <div class="title"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="group7" class="parallax__group">
            <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
              <div class="title footer"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Verdana";
  color: #ffffff;
  background: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cd-header {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: visible;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}
/* Parallax base styles
--------------------------------------------- */

.parallax {
  height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
  height: 85vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__layer--fore {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 4;
}

.parallax__layer--back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
  z-index: 3;
}

.parallax__layer--deep {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
  z-index: 2;
}

  /* style the groups
  --------------------------------------------- */

  #group1 {
    z-index: 5; /* slide over group 2 */
  }
  #group1 .parallax__layer--base {
    background: #99a478;
  }

  #group2 {
    z-index: 3; /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
  }
  #group2 .parallax__layer--back {
    background-image: url(../img/dscn5044.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .parallax__layer--back--1{
    background-image: url(../img/dscn2572.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

  }

  #group3 {
    z-index: 4; /* slide over group 2 and 4 */
  }
  #group3 .parallax__layer--base {
    background: #b4d7a8;
  }

  #group4 {
    z-index: 2; /* slide under group 3 and 5 */
  }
  #group4 .parallax__layer--deep {
    background: rgb(184,223,101);
  }

  #group5 {
    z-index: 3; /* slide over group 4 and 6 */
  }
  #group5 .parallax__layer--base {
    background-color: #99a478;
  }

  #group6 {
    z-index: 2; /* slide under group 5 and 7 */
  }
  #group6 .parallax__layer--back {
    background-image: url(../img/dscn7138.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

  }

  #group7 {
    z-index: 3; /* slide over group 7 */
  }
  #group7 .parallax__layer--base {
    background-color: #3d3536;
  }
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, это нормально. Если не активен окно самого браузера, даже не сайт, а именно окно, или может быть даже определённая вкладка с сайтом, то сайт может и не прокручиваться. Попробуйте нажать Tab и переходить к любому элементу вашего сайта и начать прокручивать страницу с помощью клавиатуры. Если работает, то скорее всего проблема не в коде, а в системе работы самого браузера/системы. Хотя, если это второй вариант, то это даже не проблема, это просто устроено таким образом.